Warning about no more close votes should be on 'close' button
This post is only slightly related to this one, and I am aware of the vote count at the bottom right corner of the close window.
And, while I completely agree that disabling or hiding the 'close' button/link is not a user friendly approach, I also think that making the user go through the entire process of closing, before showing the message, is not friendly either.
Below is the message you get after choosing to close, choosing the reason (potentially going to the second window), and validating your choice.
This message should be on the 'close' button/link click.


I sometimes click on the close link without voting to close just to remind myself of the exact descriptions, and also do so after I expended all my close votes. I wouldn't like it if that option goes away.

@MarkRotteveel technically you can also find the options in the flagging menu, under "needs improvement". So if the option ever does disappear, you have a backup :)
